# C# PublishTrimmed: how to deal with IL2104 trim warnings in dependencies

Tags: .net

> Newtonsoft.Json.dll : error IL2104: Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' produced trim warnings. For more information
> see https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/libraries [C:\Users\pclay\scs_link\link\StudioLink\StudioLink.csproj]

I have been using [Dotnet 7 trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?source=recommendations&pivots=dotnet-7-0), but the documentation does not make it clear how to exempt certain third party components from trimming if they cannot be made compatible. How can I limit trimming to only compatible assemblies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: you can't.

---

Long version:

The warning stems from the third-party assembly but relates to how the problem cannot be solved by not trimming that assembly itself.

In this case, it pertains to how Newtonsoft.Json uses reflection in how it serializes data. The Newtonsoft APIs aren't annotated correctly for this, and ILLink detects that it uses unguarded reflection in some cases. Guarding is done by attributing parts of the API (especially type parameters and not-concrete types, `object`s and interfaces).

That means, your app might have a `MyCertainDTO` type that you want to serialize using Newtonsoft. You could "root" the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` by adding a property to your project file's `PropertyGroup` like so: `<TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" />`. BUT that won't prevent the linker to throw away YOUR `MyCertainDTO` type, because that's not in Newtonsoft's assembly!

So the warning essentially means:

- either tell the provider of the third-party package to correctly annotate its package for trimming, or,
- if you're certain there will be no problem (because you made sure the trimmer won't trim your code away, for example), you can suppress the issue *in your code* by using a certain attribute (I won't name it here because it should only be used if you really know what you're doing). That won't prevent the third-party warning, though, and I'm not sure it's possible.

You can relatively safely set the linker to only trim assemblies that are trim-compatible by setting `<TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>`. That won't shut up the warnings either, but it'll keep more types and members in your assemblies "just to be safe". If you just want the warnings to go away, you can `<SuppressTrimAnalysisWarnings>true</SuppressTrimAnalysisWarnings>`, but this doesn't really solve any issues other than warnings not showing up. They're still there, you just don't see them.

---

And that's it: you can suppress these warnings, but essentially, there's no way for you to solve the problem. A workaround can be that you implement a wrapper, suppress the underlying issue and use your wrapper directly (which is then considered trim safe). But the only way to correctly and really solve the issue is for the authors of the packages to annotate their assemblies correctly.